# How do you say "I am rested" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos

Jesus said to his disciples:

> Come apart and **rest**.

How would I then say this?

> Yes, I took the day off and now **I am well-rested**.

Could it be *"**Estoy bien descansado**"*?

Comment: Could you clarify? The title asks a question but the text of the question seems to have been cut off.

Comment: Please, visit [tour], [help] and especially [ask] to know more about the site and how to ask a good question. **Help us to help you** by asking in a way we can understand what to need to know. Also, we don't just offer translation services. We try to **explain and teach** so we like to see that people do some research or show some effort instead of demanding a translation. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: Reopening, although I think there's little here than just a plain translation that can be accomplished with a dictionary: (to rest - descansar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=rest)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for translations without presenting alternatives nor showing your work is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Could it be "Estoy bien descansado."?

Answer (score 1):

In Spain I should say "he descansado bien" (I am well-rested).

Descansar is usually used as verb. I think I can count with the fingers of my hand the times I see it as adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to say "Ya descansé", but also you can say "Estoy descansado" or "Estoy bien descansado" (like well rested)

Comment: Why? Please, aswers should **Explain**. If you haven't done so visit [help], [tour] and [answer]. Thanks.

Comment: The use of "Ya descansé" sounds like a latinamerican thing, in Spain i don't think you'll hear this as often as you seem to believe (Source: living in Spain).

Answer (score 0):

A good translation to "Yes, I took the day off and now I am well-rested." is this:

> Si, me tomé el día libre y ahora estoy **(bien) repuesto/recuperado**

where *recuperado* means **recovered** which works the same as *rested*